# Possible to use logstash to merge data from multiple files?

Tags: xml, csv, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I've got two files, an xml file and a csv file. When I ingest the data from the csv file I want to add_fields from the xml file.

Here's what my xml looks like

```
<Root>
  <Date>07.31.2015</Run>
  <Customer>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <ID>12345</ID>
  </Customer>
</Root>
```

And here is my csv

```
column1,column2,column3
example1,example2,example3
example4,example5,example6
```

Now I want to pull Date and ID from the xml file and add those fields to each row of the csv when I pull it into elastic search, so something like this:

```
{
  "_index" : "indx-2.0",
  "_type" : "logfile",
  "_id" : "abcdefg",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"message":["column1,column2,column3"],"Date":"07.31.2015", "CID": "12345"(etc)}
}
{
  "_index" : "indx-2.0",
  "_type" : "logfile",
  "_id" : "abcdefh",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"message":["example1,example2,example3"],"Date":"07.31.2015", "CID": "12345"(etc)}
}
{
  "_index" : "indx-2.0",
  "_type" : "logfile",
  "_id" : "abcdefi",
  "_score" : 1.0,
  "_source":{"message":["example4,example5,example6"],"Date":"07.31.2015", "CID": "12345"(etc)}
}
```

Is this kind of thing possible using logstash (And what would the .conf file look like)?

Answer (score 0):

Quick ideas:

You could load the xml into elasticsearch and use the elasticsearch{} filter to query the document and merge it into your csv data.

If the xml data doesn't change much (once per csv batch, etc), you could use mutate->add_field with a hardcoded value.